# HTMLTestRunner Report for Python is very large and takes time to open in outlook

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the HTMLTestRunner report for my Selenium Webdriver Python tests, URL: http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

When the test run completes I am emailing the report to our dev and test team.
The email which arrives in Outlook is 2MB and it takes quite some time to open the email.
There are 59 Test Cases in my test suite.
Is there a way I can shorten this so it does not take time to open in the email?

My code snippet for sending the email is:

```
def send_selenium_report():
fileToSend_part1 = r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html"

with open(fileToSend_part1, "rt") as f:
    text = f.read()
msg = MIMEText(text, "html")
msg['Subject'] = "ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test"
msg['to'] = "cc4_server_dev@company.onmicrosoft.com"
msg['From'] = "system@company.com"

s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
s.close()
```

My code snippet for the HTMLRunner TestSUite is:

```
import sys
import unittest
from HTMLTestRunner2 import HTMLTestRunner
from Utilities.HelperMethods import get_datetime_now
import os
import unittest
import Regression_TestCase.RegressionProjectEdit_TestCase


class Test_Suite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):


        tests_regression = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(
            Regression_TestCase.RegressionProjectEdit_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase_Project_Edit)


        regression_tests = unittest.TestSuite([tests_regression])


def suite():
    """
        Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite.
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Regression_TestCase.RegressionProjectEdit_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase_Project_Edit))
    return test_suite


mySuit = suite()

# output to a file
test_result_dir = os.path.join(
    r"E:\\test_runners 2 edit project\\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\\TestReport\\")


# open the report file
outfile = file(test_result_dir + "\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html", "wb")

# configure HTMLTestRunner options
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                                       title='Test Report',
                                       description='Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test')

# run the suite using HTMLTestRunner
runner.run(mySuit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # unittest.main()
    HTMLTestRunner.main()
```

I have uploaded the report file to a shared location.  The link is: http://www.filedropper.com/clearcore501automatedguitestreport

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Did you try to customize your report? May be it includes excessive styles,  scripts, log outputs, comments etc.?

Comment: It is using a plugin, I have mentioned the link above.  I don't know how I can customize it.  I was thinking maybe I could use the BeautifulSoup API to extract the pass, fail out of the report and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you post the report on some website (or maybe a shared folder, yuck) and then send a link to it. Another alternative is to zip the file and send it.

Comment: I have uploaded the report.  The link is: http://www.filedropper.com/clearcore501automatedguitestreport

Comment: No, I meant instead of attaching the HTML report to an email, upload it to a site and send out a link to everyone on your mailing list.

Comment: The managers would like the report inside the email body.  They want to see it straight away when opening the email an not click a link to see the report.

Comment: @RiazLadhani I guess I don't understand the distinction. If you attach the report to an email, they still have to double-click the report to open it. How's that really different than just putting a link? Have you considered extracting a summary from the report and putting that directly in the email and then putting a link to the full report? You could also use the suggestion of zipping the report. This question is really less about programming and more about Outlook and how it processes HTML attachments.

Comment: Yes extracting the summary out of the report and putting that directly into the email I would like to do.  I was thinking I could use the BeautifulSoup API for Python to extract the summary

Comment: I have managed to extract the summary and test cases out of the report using BeautifulSoup.  Email opens quick now.